Как метод наследованного класса изменить без его переопределения?
Всех приветствую.
Сразу к делу: я пишу игру на pygame и у меня есть класс врага, наследованный от pygame.sprite.Sprite (Класс ниже)
import pygame
import random
import time
from threading import Thread, Lock
from random import choices
from main import damage


class BaseEnemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image="res/textures/base_texture.png", speed_arr=(1000, 5), starter_pose=(1920/2, 1080/2), phb=None, r=50, d=10, reward=10):
        # phb - player_heal_bar (Не подумайте что-то не то), r - radius, d - damage
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        try:
            self.image = pygame.image.load(image).convert_alpha()
        except:
            image = "res/textures/base_texture.png"
            self.image = pygame.image.load(image).convert_alpha()
        self.image.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.upd = Thread(target=self.update, args=[phb, r, d])
        self.upd.start()
        self.speed_arr = speed_arr
        self.rect.center = starter_pose
        self.starter = starter_pose
        self.reward = reward
        self.alive = True


    def update(self, phb, r, d):
        while self.alive:
            try:
                time.sleep(0.17)
                t_x = self.rect.center[0]
                t_y = self.rect.center[1]
                for i in range(self.speed_arr[0]):
                    self.rect.x += random.randint(-self.speed_arr[1], self.speed_arr[1])
                    self.rect.y += random.randint(-self.speed_arr[1], self.speed_arr[1])
                if self.rect.center[0] < 0:
                    self.rect.center = (random.randint(1000, 1900), random.randint(500, 1000))
                if self.rect.center[0] > 1920:
                    self.rect.center = (random.randint(1000, 1900), random.randint(500, 1000))
                if self.rect.center[1] < 0:
                    self.rect.center = (random.randint(1000, 1900), random.randint(500, 1000))
                if self.rect.center[1] > 1080:
                    self.rect.center = (random.randint(1000, 1900), random.randint(500, 1000))
                damage(choices([d, 0], weights=[.01, .99]), phb)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                self.kill()
                break

    def checker(self, phb, r, ev):
        if self.rect.colliderect(pygame.Rect(int(pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0] - r/2), int(pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1] - r/2), r, r)):
            if pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN in list(map(lambda x: x.type, ev)):
                self.kill()
                phb.add_cash(self.reward)
                try:
                    self.image = pygame.image.load("res/textures/killed.png").convert_alpha()
                except:
                    image = "res/textures/base_texture.png"
                    self.image = pygame.image.load(image).convert_alpha()
                self.alive = False

Да, знаю возможно что-то написано неправильно, что-то вообще лишнее, но имею что имею.
Так вот. Мне надо добавить буквально одну строку в метод kill(), при этом переопределять его с нуля не сильно хочется. Как можно наследовать метод и можно ли это вообще сделать?
P.S. Если еще кто знает, то пожалуйста подскажите как сделать спрайту более плавное перемещение. (метод update())
Спасибо за любую помощь!

Ну, напрямую внутри родительского метода что-то поменять не получится (по крайней мере без чёрной магии типа inspect).
Но если вам нужно выполнить дополнительную логику сразу до или сразу после метода, то можно сделать так:
class Child:

    def some_method(self, args):
        super().some_metod(args)
        extra_logic()    # Ваша добавочная логика

Специальная функция super() нужна для обращения к родительскому классу.
Если же есть необходимость поменять что-то в середине родительского метода, то можно вынести в методе родителя ту логику, которую планируется переопределять в потомках, в отдельный метод, и переопределять только его:
class Parent:

    def some_method():
        some_logic()  # Много логики, которая будет одинаковой
        self.custom_logic()  # Логика, которую можно менять в потомках
        some_logic()  # Много логики, которая будет одинаковой

    def custom_logic(self):
        # В потомках переопределяем только этот метод
        pass


Спасибо, первый вариант - это то что мне было нужно. Не подскажете еще по плавному перемещению спрайтов?

Нет, с pygame я не работал ) Лучше задайте это отдельным вопросом.
